# Filter table using select option in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selected" id="department" name="department"  
(ngModelChange)="onSelect(selected)">
                                        <option value=''  >Select Department</option>
                                        <option *ngFor="let data of result" [value]="data.id" >
```

{{data.name}} 
                                        
Please i want to filter table based on the data passed from the select oprion dropdown. Any help please.

This is the table i am using

                            
                            
                            </ngx-datatable-column> -->

Answer (score 0):

We can filter the array using the selected value.

I created a stackblitz for the scenario:

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qdboig

Let us know if it helps or if you have any more questions.